# Java Equivalent to Struct Pass By Reference

Tags: java, android, data-structures, pass-by-value

In my searches, I've have seen people say use a Class but I'm not sure if a Class will work for me.

What I would like to do is call a function and pass one or more "Structures" to it by address. This way, I could tell the function to alter which ever "Structures" I pass to it.

Comment: i think u need to learn java..

Comment: It's impossible. Use the functions return value.

Comment: If passing an object won't work for you, you are out of luck.

Comment: I think you need to learn the fundamental concepts of Java first. Here is a good starting point: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html